# getting value of multidimensional javascript array in IE

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, object

I have this array (I know, technically there is no such thing as a multidimensional array in javascript) or 'object'. I want to get the value -888 like so:

```
    var thisPage = 1;

    var pagePos = {
        0: {
            left: '0',
            url: 'home',
        },
        1: {
            left: '-888',
            url: 'what_we_offer',
        },
        2: {
            left: '-1776',
            url: 'clients',
        },
        3: {
            left: '-2664',
            url: 'contact_us',
        }
    };

alert(pagePos[thisPage].left);
```

It works fine in Firefox, but not IE. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: It does work in IE. [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PeFeH/). Is this your actual code? Something else is going wrong, something we're not seeing. Is there perhaps a trailing `,` after declaring the `3` property? Because that doesn't work very well in IE.

Comment: @DavidHedlund He didn't say what version OF IE...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually duri has it below- it's the trailing commas after the url attributes that's throwing it. Cheers.

Comment: @nex: fair point. Heh, with hindsight "something we're not seeing ... perhaps a trailing comma" should've been something *I* wasn't seeing o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of trailing commas after values of `url` attributes. You can't have comma after the last value in JSON. The correct syntax is

```
var pagePos = {
    0: {
        left: '0',
        url: 'home'
    },
    1: {
        left: '-888',
        url: 'what_we_offer'
    },
    2: {
        left: '-1776',
        url: 'clients'
    },
    3: {
        left: '-2664',
        url: 'contact_us'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you turn it into an array of objects (since that's the way you're accessing it):

```
var thisPage = 1;

var pagePos = [
    {
        left: '0',
        url: 'home'
    },
    {
        left: '-888',
        url: 'what_we_offer'
    },
    {
        left: '-1776',
        url: 'clients'
    },
    {
        left: '-2664',
        url: 'contact_us'
    }
];

alert(pagePos[thisPage].left);
```

Also... remove the extra commas after the url properties.  Some browsers are OK with them, some not.

Comment: Yes- it's the extra commas after the url properties! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple ways IE might have issues with this (it's IE, cmon'). Try changing the nature of your Array to a simple Array of objects. They'll be naturally numbered this way, by the order they're initialized.

```
var pagePos = [
    {
        left: '0',
        url: 'home',
    },
    {
        left: '-888',
        url: 'what_we_offer',
    },
    {
        left: '-1776',
        url: 'clients',
    },
    {
        left: '-2664',
        url: 'contact_us',
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of a quirky way to put together an array...I'm surprised it works in any browser!  Try definining `pagePos` like this intead:

```
var pagePos = [ // note: bracket!
        {
            left: '0',
            url: 'home',
        },
        {
            left: '-888',
            url: 'what_we_offer',
        },
        {
            left: '-1776',
            url: 'clients',
        },
        {
            left: '-2664',
            url: 'contact_us',
        }
    ];
```